# How to use PECL extension from inside of framework

Tags: php, symfony, pear, pecl

I am using PECL extension [trader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.trader.php)

It works inside the ./src/MyBundle/Command/MyCommand.php without any installtion or include.

```
function calcByCode()
    \trader_ma($array, 5, TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA);
}
```

however inside the Controller

./src/MyBundle/Controller/MyController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
    \trader_ma($array, 5, TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA); 
    //(or trader_ma($array, 5, TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA);)

    return $this->render('AcmeTopBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

returns error like this

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function TopBundle\MyController\trader_ma()

How can I use PECL extension inside the condroller of Symfony2 framework??

Comment: Post the fill code where you call `trader_ma`

Comment: I changed the article though, I just use `trader_ma` quite simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly a case of the extension not being installed correctly. To know if the extension if installed correctly or not, make use of [phpinfo](https://secure.php.net/phpinfo)  for both cli and web ( cgi / fpm ).

There is a chance that the extension is enabled only in the php.ini for PHP CLI and not for fpm / cgi ( web server ) . So make sure you enable the trader module in the appropriate php.ini file .

Comment: I compared two phpini() from cgi and command line.
I found out there is the table named as trader in phpinfo command line. 

`trader`

`Trader Technical Analysis Library Support => enabled`
`Version => 0.4.0`
`TA-Lib version => 0.4.0 (Nov 18 2016 11:24:08)`

However there is no table about trader in phpinfo from cgi.
However I have confirmed I use the same php.ini  `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini` on both environment.
How can I fix this??

Comment: So now, I think I can summarize my problem, **PECL extention does not enabled on cgi**.

Comment: AH,,,,,, I have restarted the apache and found out it works.. Thank you very much Vamsi.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be looking for the function within the namespace for your class. Since it works in a vanilla function, that would seem to confirm that.

> undefined function TopBundle\MyController\trader_ma()

Try telling it to look in the namespace root

```
public function indexAction()
{
    \trader_ma($array, 5, TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA);
    return $this->render('AcmeTopBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

Comment: I have tried `\trader_ma` though, it doesn't work. Some classes like \DataTime works well as you said. However in this case, not.

Comment: Error message is like this `Attempted to call function "trader_ma" from the global namespace.`

Comment: I have solved this problem , thank you very much ＠Machavity! You answer is also the good hint for me.